# What is the reason for computer going into a boot loop if it is switched off from the PSU switch?

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, power-supply, desktop-computer

My PC Specs:
Intel i5 4th Gen 4690 Processor
Asus B85M-E Motherboard
AITC DDR3 8GB 1600Mhz RAM
WD Blue 1TB HDD
ANTEC ATOM V450 450W Power Supply

Issue:
I shutdown windows 10 and after making sure everything is turned off (HDD, Cooling Fan, Casing Fan) I turn off power supply by flipping power supply switch. But when I turn on power supply back again and try to turn my pc on, it goes to a boot loop. HDD, CPU Fan and Casing fan start for few seconds and turn off and start again. This happens until i turn it off. Then I have to remove my RAM and reinsert it few times until pc turn on normally. But if I didn't turn the power supply switch off after shutting down, then pc starts without any issues.

Does anyone have an idea what should i do? I bought a new graphic card and i am worried that my computer won't turn on if I turn my power supply off to install it.

Comment: To me sounds like an issue with a mobo itself, or maybe the RAM. If you remove the RAM and disconnect the drives, the system should consistently be able to boot into the BIOS - if not, I'd say either the mobo or the PSU is about to fail.

Comment: I bought a new RAM and replace the previous one. It resolved the issue. Somehow my previous ram had an issue even i bought it brand new. Anyway thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Let's hope you got a warranty replacement :-) I'm going to move the comment to an answer, I'd appreciate if you accept it.

Comment: I would install a new cmos battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely reason is an issue with a motherboard itself, or maybe the RAM. If you remove the RAM and disconnect the drives, the system should consistently be able to boot into the BIOS - if not, I'd say either the mobo or the PSU is about to fail.

Reasoning behind: basic troubleshooting. Simplify the setup to bare minimum to boot. If boot is successful, start adding parts one at the time. Once the problem appears, you've found the point of failure.

To identify the actual failing part, new parts are needed. For example if the failure appears when a RAM module is inserted, the problem can be the RAM or the mobo connection. To identify the exact part, test with a different RAM module. If the can now boot sequentially without failure, the original RAM module is the failing part.